# Abrindo página dentro de uma DIV (problema com página inicial)

Tags: php

Bom dia.

Estou com um sistema para abrir as páginas (linkadas no menu) dentro de uma DIV do site, está funcionando corretamente.

Porém não estou conseguindo uma coisa, definir uma pagina inicial já dentro dessa DIV.

No caso seria a minha página pages/home.php, porém não sei como deixa-la dentro da DIV quando entro no localhost/index.php.

Segue o código da página index.php

```html
   <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Moraes Automóveis</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exclusivamente esses estilos só funcionam colocando aqui na index.php, quando ponho dentro do css/css.css não dá retorno algum
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<style type="text/css">
#footer-copyright {
 color: white;
}
.section1 {
 padding-top: 55px;
}
</style>
<!--------------------------------------------------------
Esse script é pro ícone flutuante do WhatsApp no site
---------------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
var options = {
whatsapp: "+554733453668", // Número do WhatsApp
greeting_message: "Olá! Precisa de alguma ajuda?", // Texto principal
call_to_action: "Entre em contato conosco..", // Chamada para ação
position: "right", // Posição do widget na página 'right' ou 'left'
};
var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-----------------------------------------
Navbar do site - Utilizando Bootstrap3
------------------------------------------->
<center><nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-head">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="img/logo.png" width="150px">
   </a>
  </div>
<!---------------------------------------------
Início de links para carregar dentro da div
----------------------------------------------->
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
    <li>
     <a href="./index.php?pg=home">Inicio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="./index.php?pg=empresa">Empresa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="./index.php?pg=estoque">Estoque</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="./index.php?pg=financiamento">Financiamento</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="./index.php?pg=vendaseuveiculo">Venda seu veículo</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="./index.php?pg=contato">Contato</a>
    </li>
  </div>
 </div>   
</nav></center>
<!---------------
Logo do site
----------------->
 <div class="section1 row" id="logo"> 
  <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
    <img src="img/logomaior2.png">
  </div>
 </div>
<!-----------------------------
Div que receberá as páginas
------------------------------->
 <div class="container" id="conteudo"> 
  <div class="col-sm-12 w-auto p-3">
<?php   
// -----------------------
//Código em php funcionando
// -----------------------
if (isset($_GET['pg'])) { 
$Pagina = $_GET['pg'];
 if ($Pagina == "home") {
  include('pages/home.php');
 } else if ($Pagina == "empresa") {
  include('pages/empresa.php');
 } else if ($Pagina == "estoque") {
  include('pages/estoque.php');
 } else if ($Pagina == "") {
  include('pages/home.php');
 } else {
  include("pages/error.php");
 }
}
?>
  </div>
 </div>
<!--------------------
Rodapé do site
--------------------->
<footer id="myFooter"> 
    <div id="footer-copyright" class="container">
        © 2020 Copyright - Moraes Automóveis
    </div>
    <div class="footer-social">
        <a href="https://fb.com/moraesautomoveis" class="social-icons"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/moraesautomoveis" class="social-icons"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o problema está na parte que verificas o `$_GET['pg']`. Visto que não estás tratar do caso em quem `$_GET['pg']` não está definido, se acederes à homepage sem `?pg=home` no url, não será feito o `include` de nenhuma página.

Experimenta ajustar essa porção do código para o seguinte:

```php
// -----------------------
//Código em php funcionando
// -----------------------
$Pagina = "home"; // Página a apresentar se nenhuma estiver definida
if (isset($_GET['pg'])) {
    $Pagina = $_GET['pg'];
}

if ($Pagina == "home") {
    include('pages/home.php');
} else if ($Pagina == "empresa") {
    include('pages/empresa.php');
} else if ($Pagina == "estoque") {
    include('pages/estoque.php');
} else if ($Pagina == "") {
    include('pages/home.php');
} else {
    include("pages/error.php");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Diogo. Deu certo.